# while loop not working in email password checker (python)

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, passwords

```
users = {
1: {"first_name": "Tom", "last_name": "Smith", "email": "tom@email.com", "password": "123123"},

2: {"first_name": "Simon", "last_name": "Stevens", "email": "simon@email.com", "password": "password1234"},

3: {"first_name": "Laura", "last_name": "Laurens", "email": "laura@email.com", "password": "laura1234"},

4: {"first_name": "Gabriel", "last_name": "Mitchel", "email": "gab@email.com", "password": "laura12534"}
}

email_input = input("What's your email?")
password_input = input("What's your password?")

for key, info in users.items():
    name = info["first_name"]
    last_name = info["last_name"]
    email = info["email"]
    password = info["password"]

while email_input != email and password_input != password:
    print("wrong password/email")
    email_input = input("What's your email?")
    password_input = input("What's your password?")    
print("You're logged in",name)
```

The goal of this script is to ask the user their email and password and if it's incorrect then using a while loop it should keep asking the user for their details until the user provides the correct email and password.

It doesn't work even when I enter correct email/password the first time.

Comment: Your `and` should be `or`.

Comment: [works for me](https://tio.run/##jZJda8IwFIbv8yuy3GihOPwYDEG2u91sVw7GGCJR0zasSUqSrhTxt3f5sLFa3CylH@d9c55zTlLUOhN8@ljIpikVkQou4B6M53CPEiqVXnPMCJpD9C4YiiHKcSe2ZFRnNkoYprmNaMGe3c9o6/0FVqoScmfF8WRqbnSIAZj0AUvKBO8jNPkhXJ1BlHVex7TfhjVzsGkf9opLiXswG72E5dZ5HebkQJr1SS94IynJe6w3qreZjwdWijf/kh4sChwAcMY15UWpzZ659xB9ZFgPFKxFKaEzPKEItFn@Mrce6weJkPCb1LExJsI8oDsZI6oJU8NoDqC5bB8uVSK@ui2vnBpaDZZT897hqguqH4FX2lKCGKawAqDKaE5gt/e7xTEX5jt40arR2oivupCUm84rKXgapHtPj0513TTWbq03jtYuAccaPkU5kATmIk3JzqxDsZ1O1DRnpwCctv0X)

Comment: You're only comparing the user's input to the *last* username and password in your `users` dictionary, in case that wasn't obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code with Corrections**

```
users = {
    1: {"first_name": "Tom", "last_name": "Smith", "email": "tom@email.com", "password": "123123"},

    2: {"first_name": "Simon", "last_name": "Stevens", "email": "simon@email.com", "password": "password1234"},

    3: {"first_name": "Laura", "last_name": "Laurens", "email": "laura@email.com", "password": "laura1234"},

    4: {"first_name": "Gabriel", "last_name": "Mitchel", "email": "gab@email.com", "password": "laura12534"}
}


found = False
while not found:                                # loop until match found
    # Get login credentials
    email_input = input("What's your email?")
    password_input = input("What's your password?") 
    
    # check each dictionary for email and password
    for key, info in users.items():
        if email_input == info["email"] and password_input == info["password"]:
            # Found match, so get name
            name = info["first_name"]            
            last_name = info["last_name"]        
            found = True                        # set flag to terminate while loop
            break                               # found match
    else:
        print("wrong password/email")           # Break not encountered in for loop, so did not find match

print(f"You're logged in {name} {last_name}")
```